# c++ Memory allocated wrong?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, new-operator

I've been working on a single line of code for three days and I found out it seems the memory allocated not as I supposed.

I have a `Buffer` class which owns two `int` variables and a `*float` pointer, which I think takes up 16 bytes in memory.

I also have a `Film` class which holds two `int` variables, two `Vec3f` variables, and a `Buffer*` pointer. `Vec3f` is a class which holds three `float` variables.

Class definitions are as follows:

```
class Buffer {
    public:
        int _width;
        int _heigth;
        Vec3f *_data;

        Buffer(int w, int h) : _width(w), _height(h) {
            _data = new Vec3f(_width*_heigth);
        }
        ~Buffer();
    };

struct Film {
        int _width;
        int _height;
        Vec3f _left_bottom_corner;
        Vec3f _left_up_corner;
        Buffer *_cbuffer;

        Film(int w, int h, Buffer *cbuffer) : _width(w), _height(h), _cbuffer(cbuffer) {}   
};

template<typename ElementType, unsigned Size>
    class Vector {
    private:
        std::array<ElementType, Size> _v;
};
typedef Vector<float, 3> Vec3f;
```

And I initialize them like this:

```
int w = 5; int h = 5;
Buffer *b = new Buffer(w, h);
Film *film = new Film(w, h, b);
```

Something weird happened when I tried to assign values to `film->_cbuffer->data[i]` so I debugged the program

```
std::cout << b << std::endl;
std::cout << b->_data << std::endl;
std::cout << film << std::endl;
```

and the output is

```
0x7fa500500000
0x7fa500600000
0x7fa500600010
```

I think a `Buffer` instance should take up 16 bytes and a `Film` instance should take up to **4*2 + 4*3*2 + 8** bytes. But what really matters is the size of `Buffer._data` array, which I allocated manually with `new` operator.

From the given result the array takes up to 16 bytes and this is fixed for all `w` and `h` I've tested and this is not what I suppose. Take `w=5, h=5` for example, the size of the array should be **5 * 5 * 8** .

For the memory allocated like this, `film._width` would be modified when 
When `w` and `h` are both set to `1`, the memory is allocated "right" accidentally:

```
0x7f90b9d00000
0x7f90b9d00010
0x7f90b9d00020
```

Comment: Forget everything you know anout new and delete. Use std::vector.

Comment: @n.m. gave you the good advice. Forget `new` and fix you code using `std::vector<Vec3f>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Vec3f(_width*_heigth)` doesn't initialize any array of variable length. The size of `Vec3f` array field is always 3, and this is probably not what you want in your buffer constructor. BTW, you don't have any `Vector::Vector(some_kind_of_int)` constructor at all.

Probably you want to use (runtime-known size) `std::vector` in your buffer instead of something based on (compiletime-known constant (AKA `constexpr`) length) `std::array`.

Comment: @ AndreyS Scherbakov It seems the literal answer to my question is the use of wrong syntax with `new` operator. But `std::vector` is a better practice.

Comment: @Jinglei.Y It's an interesting question which layer is primary. Say, modern Natural Language Processing believes that word inventory tells much more about the semantics of some text than its syntax and structure.. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Do you not see a problem here?

```
Buffer(int w, int h) {
   _data = new Vec3f(_width*_heigth);
}
```

Is it not strange that uninitialized `_width` and `_heigth` used? Probably you want:

```
Buffer(int w, int h): _width(w), _heigth(h) {
   _data = new Vec3f[_width*_heigth];
}
```

The line below outputs the address of `Vec3f` array pointed by `_data`.

```
std::cout << b->_data << std::endl;
```

If you are going to look at the address of `_data` within the `Buffer` object, it should be

```
std::cout << &b->_data << std::endl;
```

Comment: The initialisation of `_data` would also be usually better in the initialiser list.

Comment: @Peter It is better to use `std::vector<Vec3f>` and forget manual memory management.

Comment: @S.M. So sorry, I made a mistake when copy and paste my code. I use the initialiser list in the constructor. So `_width` and `_height` should be initialized here.

Comment: @S.M. I thought `b->_data` is a pointer so it is fine to use `std::cout << b->_data` to print out the address `_data` is pointing to ?

Comment: @Jinglei.Y All addresses are useless.

Comment: @Jinglei.Y Please refactor your code by using `std::vector` and then be kind to note us if the problem went.

Comment: @S.M. The code works with `std::vector`. I just still wonder why the previous problem happens..

Comment: @S.M. Ok. I know where's the problem. I use the wrong syntax when allocate memory using `new`. But thanks I'll use `std::vector` instead.